# How to put values to const char **?

Tags: c, char, constants

If I declare a variable const char ** stringTable, how should I be able to put values to it if it is a const? (It has to be const because a function I am supposed to use takes const char ** as a parameter.)

Edit:
No you cannot convert from char ** to const char ** implicitly. Compiler complains:
cannot convert parameter 3 from 'char **' to 'const char **'

Answer (score 5):

Wow, I'm surprised nobody got this! Maybe I can get a necromancer badge. Implicit const casting only scans one level deep. So a `char*` can become a `const char*` but it won't dig deep enough inside the a `char**` type to find what needs to be changed to make it a `const char**`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print3( const char **three ) {
        for ( int x = 0; x < 3; ++ x ) {
                cerr << three[x];
        }
}

int main() {
         // "three" holds pointers to chars that can't be changed
        const char **three = (const char**) malloc( sizeof( char** ) * 3 );
        char a[5], b[5], c[5]; // strings on the stack can be changed
        strcpy( a, "abc" ); // copy const string into non-const string
        strcpy( b, "def" );
        strcpy( c, "efg" );
        three[0] = a; // ok: we won't change a through three
        three[1] = b; // and the (char*) to (const char*) conversion
        three[2] = c; // is just one level deep
        print3( three ); // print3 gets the type it wants
        cerr << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm also surprised that nobody else got this, good job sir :)

Answer (score 4):

Apart from other mentions that you can pass `char**` into function that takes `const char **`,

`const char**` is a non-const pointer to `const char*`, you can declare it and freely put values of type `const char*` in it.

On the other hand, you would not be able to do it, if you declared it as `const char * const *` or `const char * const * const`.

```
yourfunc(const char **p);
...
const char *array_str[10];
array_str[0] = "foo"; /* OK, literal is a const char[] */
yourfunc(array_str);
```

Here is what `cdecl` says:

```
cdecl> explain const char **table
declare table as pointer to pointer to const char
cdecl> explain const char * const *table
declare table as pointer to const pointer to const char
cdecl> explain const char * const * const table
declare table as const pointer to const pointer to const char
```

Answer (score 3):

That const declaration is a quarantee of the function, you dont have to fullfill it. That means the function will keep your array untouched (it will just read). So you can pass a nonconst variable to a function expecting const.

Comment: You can pass a `char*` to a function expecting `const char*`. You cannot pass `char**` as a `const char**`. Not that it's much of a problem, the implicit cast only works one level deep for simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a `char **` to a function declared as taking a `const char **` -- Might be worth taking a look at the [documentation for const](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/888bfst6(VS.80).aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 1):

`char **` can be converted to `const char **`, so if you want to **call** a function which takes a `const char **` as a parameter, just supply your `char **` and it'll be implicitly converted.

If you want to **write** a function which takes a `const char **` as parameter and then modifies the `char` data it references, you're breaking the contract with your compiler, even if you might get it to work via casts!

Comment: You can change the pointer, just not the data it points too. eg: const char **c; const char *str = "my string"; c = &str;//legal

Comment: Additionaly its legal to change the pointer the const char ** points to ie: *c = str//legal

Answer (score 1):

With my compiler (gcc version 3.4.4 in cygwin), I found that I could pass `char *` to `const char *`,  but not `char **` to `const char **`, unlike what most of the answers are saying.

Here is one way you can build something up that works; maybe it will help you.

```
void printstring( const char **s ) {
  printf( "%s\n", *s );
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

  char *x = "foo";  // here you have a regular mutable string

  const char *x2 = x;  // you can convert that to a constant string

  const char **y = &x2;  // you can assign the address of the const char *

  printstring(y);


}
```

Comment: `char *x = "foo"` shouldn't compile because "foo" is `const char*`. There's no need for `x2` because you can assign a `char*` into a `const char**` array.

Answer (score 0):

you can un-const char* by using a cast operator: (char*)

```
void do_something(const char* s)
{
char* p=(char*)s;
p[0]='A';
}
```

use the same idea with the arrays char**

Answer (score 0):

`const char **` indicates that the underlying character is constant.  So, while you can't do something like this:

```
const char **foo = ...;
**foo = 'a';   // not legal
```

but there is nothing preventing you from manipulating the pointer itself:

```
// all the following is legal
const char **foo = 0;

foo = (const char **)calloc(10, sizeof(const char *));

foo[0] = strdup("foo");
foo[1] = strdup("baz");
```

That said, if you did want to modify the actual character data, you could use a non-const pointer and cast it:

```
char **foo = ...;
func((const char **)foo);
```